# Trello Api: Php Curl error empty reply from server

Tags: php, api, curl, trello

I want to use the Trello Api to create a new card when certain events happen in my webapplication. I want to use Curl to do the request. This is my code:

```
$url = "https://api.trello.com/1/cards?key=".$key."&token=".$token."&name=".$name."&idList=".$idList;

# init curl
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, TRUE); // make sure we see the sended header afterwards
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

# dont care about ssl
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

# download and close
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$request =  curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT);
$error = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

I tried to use the same url with fiddler and it worked. However with this code I get back the error "Empty reply from server".
Anybody any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of putting the arguments in the URL, try putting them in CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.

This worked for me:

```
$url = "https://api.trello.com/1/cards";
$fields = "key=$key&token=$token&name=$name&idList=$idList";

# init curl
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, TRUE); // make sure we see the sended header afterwards
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

# dont care about ssl
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

# download and close
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$request =  curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT);
$error = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```